# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content in updating laravel 5.8 to laravel 7.X

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-7

i am trying to composer require laravel/framework this command
but this error create what is the problem please help to give suggestion thank you in advance

```
sing version ^7.25 for laravel/framework
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.25.0
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38, 5.8.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0 requires illuminate/support 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.*|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38, 5.8.x-dev], illuminate/support[5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.24, v6.18.25, v6.18.26, v6.18.27, v6.18.28, v6.18.29, v6.18.3, v6.18.30, v6.18.31, v6.18.32, v6.18.33, v6.18.34, v6.18.35, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v5.8.38].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.10|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.11|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.12|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.13|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.14|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.15|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.16|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.17|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.18|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.19|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.20|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.21|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.22|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.23|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.24|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.25|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.26|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.27|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.28|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.29|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.30|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.31|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.32|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.33|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.34|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.35|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.5|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.6|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.7|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.8|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.9|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.25 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v7.25.0].
    - Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-dump-server (locked at 1.3.0, required as ^1.0) -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-dump-server[1.3.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This is my composer.json file information you can see all the information here thank you.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "brian2694/laravel-toastr": "^5.5",
        "darryldecode/cart": "~4.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "spatie/db-dumper": "^2.14",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.4",
        "stevebauman/location": "^3.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.41",
        "torann/geoip": "^1.0",
        "ext-http": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
        "TelescopeServiceProvider"
        ]
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't upgrade from `5.8` to `7.x` directly; you need to follow the upgrade guide: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade and after that https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade.

Comment: `beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.3.0` requires Laravel 5 or 6. Use `beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.4.0` for Laravel 7 support. Other than that follow the upgrade guides as stated in Tim Lewis' comment

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the given error messages? Which parts are unclear?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple trick run this install dump server according to your Laravel version:

```
composer require --dev beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
```